# A Large Entity Table vs Related to the Large Entity Additional Entity?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design, entity-framework-core, architecture

I am working on a project where I cannot make 100% independent architectural decisions.
I was asked to convert a JSON field in an SQL Server database table into the relational data model from a JSON varchar field.

`{"TotalAmount":50000.0,"Level":2,"NavigationProperty3Id":2}` or `{"AmountAdded":6,"ProgressValue":9,"IsCompleted":true,"NavigationProperty4Id":2,"AmountLeftToReach":49991}` or `{"Code":"stringValue1","BaseAmount":200.0}`

The option I am most likely expected to implement in the large table with many additional properties.
The project's teamlead usually says that when we "combine" many fields of a database table into 1 single entity, it increases the performance of the database (He calls it a de-normalization of the Db) so that the entity will look like this:

```
[Table("LargeEntities")]
public class LargeEntity
{
    [Key] 
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    public long? NavigationProperty1Id { get; set; }
    public long? NavigationProperty2Id { get; set; }
    public ENavigationProperty3Type NavigationProperty3Type { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalData { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(NavigationProperty1Id))]
    public virtual AccountRelatedEntity1 AccountRelatedEntity1 { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(NavigationProperty2Id))]
    public virtual AccountRelatedEntity2 AccountRelatedEntity2 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(NavigationProperty3Id))]             // New
    public virtual AccountRelatedEntity3 AccountRelatedEntity3 { get; set; }    // New

    [ForeignKey(nameof(NavigationProperty4Id))]             // New
    public virtual AccountRelatedEntity4 AccountRelatedEntity4 { get; set; }    // New

    public decimal? TotalAmount { get; set; }               // New
    public int? Level { get; set; }                         // New
    public int? NavigationProperty3Id { get; set; }         // New

    public bool? IsCompleted { get; set; }                  // New
    public decimal? AmountLeftToReach { get; set; }         // New
    public decimal? AmountAdded { get; set; }               // New
    public decimal? ProgressValue { get; set; }             // New
    public bool? IsCalculatedCorrectly { get; set; }        // New
    public int? NavigationProperty4Id { get; set; }         // New

    public string? Code { get; set; }                       // New
    public decimal? BaseAmount { get; set; }                // New

    [NotMapped]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Under the "// new" comment are the fields which were de-serialized into the relational model.

The option I really think would be the best is to create a separate additional entity Called Related Entity, because there are 3 cases:

1. `TotalAmount, Level, NavigationProperty3Id` are not null but the case 2 and 3 props are null
2. the `NavigationProperty4Id, IsCalculatedCorrectly, AmountAdded, ProgressValue, IsCompleted, AmountLeftToReach` are not null but the case 1 and 3 props are null
3. `Code, BaseAmount` are not null but the case 2 and 3 props are null;

```
[Table("RelatedEntities")]
public class RelatedEntity
{
    public long LargeEntityId { get; set; }                 // New

    [ForeignKey(nameof(LargeEntityId))]                     // New
    public virtual LargeEntity LargeEntity { get; set; }                            // New
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(NavigationProperty3Id))]             // New
    public virtual AccountRelatedEntity3 AccountRelatedEntity3 { get; set; }    // New

    [ForeignKey(nameof(NavigationProperty4Id))]             // New
    public virtual AccountRelatedEntity4 AccountRelatedEntity4 { get; set; }    // New

    public decimal? TotalAmount { get; set; }               // New
    public int? Level { get; set; }                         // New
    public int? NavigationProperty3Id { get; set; }         // New

    public bool? IsCompleted { get; set; }                  // New
    public decimal? AmountLeftToReach { get; set; }         // New
    public decimal? AmountAdded { get; set; }               // New
    public decimal? ProgressValue { get; set; }             // New
    public bool? IsCalculatedCorrectly { get; set; }        // New
    public int? NavigationProperty4Id { get; set; }         // New

    public string? Code { get; set; }                       // New
    public decimal? BaseAmount { get; set; }                // New
}
```

Update: I wonder if the amount of unused null fields in the large entity option won't increase the amount of disk storage space compared to the "related entity" option and would it really increase the performance when using just 1 table and not 2 or even 4 tables? I even wonder if converting from json into table fields would improve anything?

Comment: Select architecture depend on your logic and table space and queries and develop and.....?why do you want separate tables?

Comment: please see this site about optimize null values: https://www.sqlshack.com/optimize-null-values-storage-consumption-using-sql-server-sparse-columns/

Comment: I have experience with big data of several terabyte, it was in one table or several tables it had good performance
With 1 or 2 table, you are more concerned about space, partition and indexes
with a lot of tables you are more concerned about join and Maintenance and complex classes
In my experience, separate tables are better, but it depends on the business(Logic)